# Best suited NoSQL database for Content Recommender

Tags: nosql, couchdb, cassandra

I am currently working in a project which includes migrating a content recommender from MySQL to a NoSQL database for performarce reasons. Our team has been evaluating some alternatives like MongoDB, CouchDB, HBase and Cassandra. The idea is to choose a database that is capable of running in a single server or in a cluster.
So far we have discarded the use of Hbase due to its dependency on a distributed environment. Even having the idea of scaling horizontally, we need to run the DB in a single server for a little while in production. MongoDB was also discarded because it does not support map/reduce features. 
We have still 2 alternatives and we have no solid background to decide. Any guidance or help is appreciated

NOTE: I do not pretend to create a religion-like discussion with non-founded arguments. It is a strictly technical question to be discussed in the problem's context

Comment: 1) MongoDb does support MapReduce (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce)
2) The primary advantage of a NoSQL database is the ability to scale out.  On a single box they are (generally) beaten hands-down by commercial RDBMS like Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Graph databases are usually considered as best suited for recommendation engines, since a lot of the recommendation algorithms are actually graph based. I recommend looking into [Neo4J](http://neo4j.org/) - it can handle billions of nodes/edges on a single machine and it supports a so-called high availability mode which is a master-slave setup with automatic master selection.